# R group_by - how to group by orderID?

Tags: r, dplyr

For some reason I can't group  and sum my data.

```
  amazon2 <- amazon %>% 
  group_by(amazon.order.id, quantity.shipped) %>%  
  summarize(amazon2, quantity = sum(quantity.shipped, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**glimpse shows this:**

> Groups: amazon.order.id [388] $ amazon.order.id  
>   "204-0311626-3448315", "204-9226726-5233164", "026-2318018-... $
>   quantity.shipped  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
>   1, 1, 1, 1,...

The result just gives me the cell 491 and nothing else.

Comment: Is the amazon orderID format too complex to group?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `group_by` does. It does not summarize anything. Rather, all following functions are applied group-wise. Have a look at the [examples here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html)

Comment: Also maybe have a look at how to write a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5028841). It's neither entirely clear what you want to do with your data nor how your data looks.

Comment: Another good resource is [this tutorial](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html#grouped-operations)

Comment: well running this results in just 1 cell with a total figure and I lose all the orderIDs:
amazon2 <- as.data.frame(amazon) %>% 
  select(amazon.order.id, quantity.shipped) %>% 
  group_by(amazon.order.id) %>%  
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity.shipped))

Answer (score 0):

Read your code, line by line, and then compare to your last line of text.

You do not anywhere specify that you want to `sum` anything.

Try editing the last line to

```
group_by(amazon.order.id) %>% summarise(sum(quantity.shipped))
```

and then go read https://datacarpentry.org/R-genomics/04-dplyr.html#split-apply-combine_data_analysis_and_the_summarize()_function

Comment: All this does it give me a single cell result

Answer (score 0):

group_by won't sum the values of the groups. It will create the groups in which you can perform operations, such as summarizing.

You see that the glimpse starts with "Groups: amazon.order.id [388]". It means that there are 388 groups in your set.

Answer (score 0):

```
amazon2 <- as.data.frame(amazon) %>% 
  group_by(amazon.order.id) %>% 
  select(amazon.order.id, quantity.shipped) %>%  
  dplyr::summarise(quantity = sum(quantity.shipped))
```

seems like plyr overides dplyr causing errors.  So here's the answer.

Comment: Try not to use `plyr` at all if possible. `dplyr` is the successor of `plyr` and there shouldn't be any reasons to still use `plyr`. It will only cause you headache.